# android google map activity open more than two times , than out of memory error issue came

Tags: android, arraylist, out-of-memory, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

here, I am using google map v2 api for draw multiple path(using polyline) on google map.

Note : when click button to start new google map activity class and draw path on first time successfully.then, click back button and again start the same map activity class and draw multiple path.

then, same thing, click back button and start the same map activity means , suddenly out of memory error will be coming.

Error output..

```
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions.add(Unknown Source)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.TruckLogics.UserController.UserOrderListMapView.drawdirection(UserOrderListMapView.java:483)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.TruckLogics.UserController.UserOrderListMapView.access$1(UserOrderListMapView.java:453)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.TruckLogics.UserController.UserOrderListMapView$GetRouteTask$1.run(UserOrderListMapView.java:228)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.TruckLogics.UserController.UserOrderListMapView$GetRouteTask.onPostExecute(UserOrderListMapView.java:225)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.TruckLogics.UserController.UserOrderListMapView$GetRouteTask.onPostExecute(UserOrderListMapView.java:1)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 03:12:46.165: E/AndroidRuntime(7803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Expected output :

when start new activity, how to clear previous activity used memory..
how to clear cache memory while jumping another activity..

Comment: here i tried, when click back button, first put finish() and tried it. same error will come.again when click back button, start previous activity using intent with finish().same error will coming

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:largeHeap="true"` in Manifest's application tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Even i added this code in manifest, for 9 times its working good, but when hit the maps with 10th time, again the same problem.. OOM (out of memory) error.